# how to know all generics type values in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, design-patterns

i have simple class like below :

```
public class HelathCheck<T>
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, CircuitBreakerPolicy<T>> pollyPolicies = new Dictionary<string, CircuitBreakerPolicy<T>>();
    }
```

i am adding value like below to this Policies dynamically.

```
HelathCheck<ClassA>.pollyPolicies.Add("SportsAPI1", Policy1);
HelathCheck<ClassB>.pollyPolicies.Add("SportsAPI2", Policy2);
HelathCheck<ClassC>.pollyPolicies.Add("SportsAPI3", Policy3);
HelathCheck<ClassD>.pollyPolicies.Add("SportsAPI4", Policy4);
```

i am storing some CircuitBreakerPolicy in Dictionary object so i can use get value later.

now i want to know all value which is stored into SoapPollyPolicies from one method

something like this, basically how do i know values store in all class?

can you please give me some hints? Thanks ( is this is right question?, not sure )

```
// here i do not want to pass classA, classB..etc, just one line and all values, i wanted to get it.
                foreach (var item in HelathCheck<??>.SoapPollyPolicies) 
                {
                    response.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                }
```

may be something like this but only class ==>

https://expertcodeblog.wordpress.com/2018/02/07/c-get-all-types-that-implement-an-interface/

the closest i can reach to this is :

```
var type = typeof(HelathCheck<>);
            var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));

            foreach (var item1 in types)
            {
                //do stuff
                var prop = item1.GetField("pollyPolicies "); // FaultResponse is one of object from SOAP resposne.

                //var value= prop.GetValue("pollyPolicies");

            }
```

Comment: We're going to need some more information here. What is the structure of ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, and ClassD? Do they share a common base type or implement a common interface that you own the source code for, so that you can extend them? Please provide more code that shows exactly what you are working with and more details regarding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: what type is `response`?

Comment: @MikeHofer - yes, all class have same base class.

Comment: @GuruStron -  please ignore the response it is just example, just want to find key and value from foreach loop

Comment: Clarification whether you need code that implements what you likely need OR code that enumerates all instantiated types of a given generic type (as the question is asking currently) would help to clarify what answers actually answer the question.

Comment: code that enumerates all instantiated types of a given generic type (as the question is asking currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need generics here. You say they are a common base class so do

```
public class HelathCheck
{
    public static Dictionary<string, BreakerBase> pollyPolicies = new Dictionary<string, BreakerBase>();
}
```

and put all the obects in that one dictioanry

Comment: public class HelathCheck<T>
{
    public static Dictionary<string, T> pollyPolicies = new Dictionary<string, T>();
}

Answer (score -1):

The most accurate way of doing this would be to create an interface for your test classes, and have each test class implement that interface.

```
public interface ITestClass { }

public class TestClassA : ITestClass
{
}

public class TestClassB : ITestClass
{
}
```

In your HealthCheck class, add a type constraint:

```
public class HealthCheck<T> where T : ITestClass
{
    public static Dictionary<string, T> Policies { get; set; }        
}
```

Now, you can then enumerate over the added items using `ITestClass` as your type parameter like so:

```
public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer()
    {
        HealthCheck<TestClassA>.Policies.Add("API1", new TestClassA());
        HealthCheck<TestClassB>.Policies.Add("API2", new TestClassB());

        foreach (var policy in HealthCheck<ITestClass>.Policies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(policy.Key);
            Console.WriteLine(policy.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind making your sample to compile/run? I'm 99% sure that the output of the code  would be empty as nothing is added to `HealthCheck<ITestClass>.Policies` in the code shown in the post but since the code currently NRE it is hard to know what exactly you suggested.